# Cake3 Fixtures not being built during unit testing cake plugin

Tags: phpunit, cakephp-3.0

I have a cakephp 3.7 plugin as its own stand-alone project. But am encountering the failures below when running unit tests. It seems after moving this outside of a parent project, the fixtures are no longer being built. Not sure how to instruct cake to build them.

> Cake\Database\Exception: Cannot describe teams. It has 0 columns.

Here is my `tests/bootstrap file`. These tests were previously working until I decided to move this plugin out of the parent project.

```
<?php
$findRoot = function ($root) {
    do {
        $lastRoot = $root;
        $root = dirname($root);
        if (is_dir($root . '/vendor/cakephp/cakephp')) {
            return $root;
        }
    } while ($root !== $lastRoot);
    throw new Exception("Cannot find the root of the application, unable to run tests");
};
$root = $findRoot(__FILE__);
unset($findRoot);
chdir($root);

if (!defined('DS')) {
    define('DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);
}

define('ROOT', $root);
define('APP_DIR', 'App');
define('WEBROOT_DIR', 'webroot');
define('APP', ROOT . '/tests/');
define('CONFIG', ROOT . '/tests/config/');
define('WWW_ROOT', ROOT . DS . WEBROOT_DIR . DS);
define('TESTS', ROOT . DS . 'tests' . DS);
define('TMP', ROOT . DS . 'tmp' . DS);
define('LOGS', TMP . 'logs' . DS);
define('CACHE', TMP . 'cache' . DS);
define('CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH', ROOT . '/vendor/cakephp/cakephp');
define('CORE_PATH', CAKE_CORE_INCLUDE_PATH . DS);
define('CAKE', CORE_PATH . 'src' . DS);

require_once ROOT . '/vendor/cakephp/cakephp/src/basics.php';
require ROOT . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use Cake\Core\Configure;
use Cake\Core\Configure\Engine\PhpConfig;

try {
    Configure::config('default', new PhpConfig());
    Configure::load('app', 'default', false);
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    exit($e->getMessage() . "\n");
}

$TMP = new \Cake\Filesystem\Folder(TMP);
$TMP->create(TMP . 'cache/models', 0777);
$TMP->create(TMP . 'cache/persistent', 0777);
$TMP->create(TMP . 'cache/views', 0777);

$cache = [
    'default' => [
        'engine' => 'File',
    ],
    '_cake_core_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => '_cake_core_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'persistent/',
        'serialize' => true,
        'duration' => '+10 seconds',
    ],
    '_cake_model_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => '_cake_model_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
        'serialize' => 'File',
        'duration' => '+10 seconds',
    ],
    '_cake_method_' => [
        'className' => 'File',
        'prefix' => '_cake_method_',
        'path' => CACHE . 'models/',
        'serialize' => 'File',
        'duration' => '+10 seconds',
    ],
];

Cake\Cache\Cache::setConfig($cache);

if (file_exists($root . '/config/bootstrap.php')) {
    require $root . '/config/bootstrap.php';
}

if (!getenv('db_dsn')) {
    putenv('db_dsn=sqlite:///:memory:');
}

Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager::setConfig('test', [
    'url' => getenv('db_dsn'),
    'timezone' => 'UTC'
]);
```

phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit
    colors="true"
    stopOnFailure="false"
    bootstrap="./tests/bootstrap.php"
    >
    <php>
        <ini name="memory_limit" value="-1"/>
        <ini name="apc.enable_cli" value="1"/>
    </php>

    <!-- Add any additional test suites you want to run here -->
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="YummySearch Test Suite">
            <directory>./tests/TestCase</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>

    <!-- configure code coverage -->
    <filter>
        <whitelist>
            <directory suffix=".php">./src/</directory>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>

    <!-- Setup a listener for fixtures -->
    <listeners>
        <listener
                class="Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureInjector">
            <arguments>
                <object class="Cake\TestSuite\Fixture\FixtureManager" />
            </arguments>
        </listener>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Comment: What does you `phpunit.xml` file look like, and how are you invoking phpunit?

Comment: @ndm added phpunit.xml to question

Comment: And how and from where do you invoke phpunit?

Comment: I just run `vendor/bin/phpunit` from the project root as I do on any cake project.

Comment: And the `phpunit.xml` file is in the project root too I suppose? In that case loading fixtures should generally work. So the question is do you get this error for all fixtures, or only for a specific one? And have you made sure that you are referencing it correctly? What does the affected test case methods and the related fixture configurations look like?

Comment: All of them 14 unit tests are failing with the same Exception. The `Teams` table is the main table, it loads two associations. So they all fail on `Teams`. You can get a better idea by looking at this. Full code: https://github.com/cnizzardini/cakephp-yummy/tree/dev/maintenance

Comment: Erm... none of your testcases configures any fixtures at all? https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#loading-fixtures-in-your-test-cases

Comment: Wait, am I not actually loading in the fixtures during the TestCases?

Comment: You don't, there's no `$fixtures` property defined in any of your tests.

Comment: Facepalm. I wonder how it was working before without that in there.

Comment: Not sure... maybe it was somehow using your "production" DB.

Comment: So it appears public $fixtures = ['plugin.Yummy.Teams', 'plugin.Yummy.Divisions','plugin.Yummy.Conferences']; is the solution.

Comment: Indeed. Submit that as an answer if you'd like.